# Differential Equation Solving

Tags: derivatives

Hi I am stuck on a differential equation and don't know what to do.
$$
{dy\over dx}=x^2+2x-1,\quad y(1)=3
$$
Do I get the first and second derivative?

Comment: just integrate with respect to $x$

Comment: It looks like you want to solve the differential equation for $y(x)$. Just integrate and choose the constant of integration by using the initial condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you provided, you wish to solve $$\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2+2x-1 $$ with an initial condition of $y=3$ when $x=1$. To solve this equation, we will use separation of variables---i.e. put all $y$s on one side and all $x$s on the other. We obtain $$dy=(x^2+2x-1) dx.$$ We then integrate both sides. $$\int dy=\int (x^2+2x-1)dx \Rightarrow y=\frac{1}{3}x^3+x^2-x+C.$$ We then input the initial condition. $$3=\frac{1}{3}+1-1+C. $$ Thus, $C=\frac{8}{3}$. Consequently, $$y=\frac{1}{3}x^3+x^2-x+\frac{8}{3}. $$

Comment: ok thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = x^{2}+2x-1$$

$$\int dy = \int (x^{2}+2x-1)dx$$

$$y = \frac{x^{3}}{3}+x^{2}-x+C$$

replacing with given values, $C = \frac{8}{3}$

Comment: how do you get x^3 - x. Because when you intergrate x^3 you get x^3/3 and when you intergrate 2x you get x^2

Comment: $\int x^2 dx=x^3/3$, $\int 2x dx=x^2$, $\int -dx=-x$

Comment: Sorry I have just noticed it was a typing error on my part. It has been edited since.